# How to correctly use sscanf

Tags: arduino, scanf

I have to write an Arduino function to look up a number in the phone book.  My code doesn't work because of the condition using sscanf.  What am I doing wrong?

```
//read the phone book and put the good value in the string

void Read_ADMIN_PHONE_NUMBER(){
  String ADMIN_PHONE_NUMBER;   
  delay(1000);
  sendATcommand("AT+CPBS=\"SM\"",  500) ;   //Select the SIM phonebook
  sendATcommand("AT+CPBR=1,99",  100) ;       // To read ALL phonebook  +CPBR: 1,"690506990",129,"ANDROID"---- exemple de reponse copier du serial monitor
 
  if (1 == sscanf(fonaInBuffer, "+CPBR: %*s", &ADMIN_PHONE_NUMBER)) {
      Serial.println(F("*****"));                     
      Serial.println(ADMIN_PHONE_NUMBER);
  } else {
      Serial.println(F("**bad***"));
  }
  delay(2000);
}
```

My problem come from the sscanf.I can't put fonaInBuffer in ADMIN_PHONE_NUMBER

```
void Read_ADMIN_PHONE_NUMBER(){
 String ADMIN_PHONE_NUMBER;   
  delay(1000);

  sendATcommand("AT+CPBS=\"SM\"",  500) ;   //Select the SIM phonebook

  sendATcommand("AT+CPBR=1,99",  100) ;   // To read ALL phonebook like example: +CPBR:1,"690506990",129,"ANDROID"

  if (1 == sscanf(fonaInBuffer, "+CPBR: %*s", &ADMIN_PHONE_NUMBER)) {

      Serial.println(ADMIN_PHONE_NUMBER);
  } else {

      Serial.println(F("**bad***"));

  }

  delay(2000);
```

Comment: Tighten and correct wording; improve code formatting

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code *and* accurately describe the problem.  Please supply details of what isn't working in your sscanf; show the inputs and the results

Answer (score 0):

The `*` in `%*s` means 'do not assign', and such conversion specifications are not counted in the number of successful conversions.  Therefore, the `sscanf()` call will return 0 always (unless the scanned string is empty; then it returns `EOF`) because there is no active conversion.

Remove the `*`, or replace it with a suitable number.  If the `ADMIN_PHONE_NUMBER` is a `char ADMIN_PHONE_NUMBER[123];`, then the number you use should be (at most) 122: `%122s` — because `sscanf()` writes a null after the 122 characters if it reads 122 characters in a single 'word'.  It is not clear what `String ADMIN_PHONE_NUMBER;` means — more precise advice cannot be given because of that.

---

Reducing your code to close to an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[] = "+CPBR: 1,\"690506990\",129,\"ANDROID\"";
    char number[64];

    int n = sscanf(buffer, "+CPBR: %63s", number);
    printf("n = %d: number = [%s]\n", n, number);

    n = sscanf(buffer, "+CPBR: %*d , \" %63[^\"]", number);
    printf("n = %d: number = [%s]\n", n, number);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
n = 1: number = [1,"690506990",129,"ANDROID"]
n = 1: number = [690506990]
```

Take your pick as to which you want to use.  I've been liberal with allowed white space in the `sscanf` conversion specifications.  You can be less liberal if you prefer.

Comment: Thx for your answer.But when I move yhe * and change String ADMIN_PHONE_NUMBER; to char ADMIN_PHONE_NUMBER[50]; the problem is till there.Normaly the response is something like that +CPBR: 1,"690506990",129,"ANDROID"..and my problem is to store the phone number in a varibale

Comment: I'm not clear where your `fonaInBuffer` is defined, or how it gets data into it — that isn't visible to me in the code in the question.  You need to identify what the possible input formats are, and which parts of the input you want to capture, and then design the format string accordingly.  You say it might be: `+CPBR: 1,"690506990",129,"ANDROID"`; do you want to capture `1,"690506990",129,"ANDROID"` or `690506990` or something else? _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_   If it is not simply everything after the blank, then more information is needed.  If it is everything after the blank, your existing format, minus the `*`, should be OK.  As mentioned in my answer, I can imagine all sorts of meanings for `String ADMIN_PHONE_NUMBER;` such that using `&ADMIN_PHONE_NUMBER` in the call to `sscanf()` is wrong.  Have you printed out `fonaInBuffer`, or logged its value, or somehow looked at it before attempting the conversion?  One good thing about `sscanf()` — you can try different conversion formats if the first one you try fails.

Comment: char fonaInBuffer[64];  here is the definition of fonaInBuffer.i program it on arduino so this variable take the answer of the AT command sendATcommand("AT+CPBR=1,99",  100) ; who is sothing  like that +CPBR: 1,"690506990",129,"ANDROID".so my I want to store all this answer or just the number("690506990")

Comment: but I have try and I thing my problem come from the fonaInBuffer who is empty.I specialy don't know how to get and Read the notification into fonaInBuffer.can't you help me?

Comment: No; I can't help you with reading data into `fonaInBuffer`.  That is completely separate from the use of `sscanf()`.  What command is the converse of `sendATcommand()` that reads data from the modem?  The whole topic requires completely different information from this question, which (for the most part) started from 'there is data in `fonaInBuffer` that needs to be parsed'.  You should consider asking a new question to address that different requirement.